# Are anonymous views counted among view count?

Tags: support

Are the anonymous people who view posts add to the view count? is it unique to IP address or to the browser signature?

Comment: Yes, anonymous views are counted. I don't know what uniqueness criteria apply.

Comment: releted http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, anonymous views are counted. I don't know what uniqueness criteria apply. – Gilles Aug 18 '13 at 11:30

.

> related meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/… – Dirty-flow Aug 20 '13 at 7:54